# Most elegant way to create hash from two datasource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a building_table and api::building_table, I would like to have the data from building_table as a default but if the data doesn't exist in building_table I would like to have to get it at api::building_table.
The problem is there are attributes that might not exist in building_table but exist in api building_table. There are also columns that are different name in each table.

Here is my sample code

```
def get_building_info
  building = Building.find_by(id: params[:id])
  api_building = Api::Building.find_by(id: params[:id])
  building_hash = {}
  building_hash[:name] = building.name || api_building.name
  building_hash[:room] = building.room || api_building.room
  building_hash[:rent] = building.rent || api_building.monthly_fee
...
end
```

is there a more elegent way of doing this? btw this is in my controller.

Comment: I think that there are some "clever" solutions being suggested, but your approach is easy to read and understand, and you should stick with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic approach, accepting the list of keys as an argument:

```
def get_building_info(keys = %i[name room rent].zip(%i[name room fee]))
  building = Building.find_by(id: params[:id])
  api_building = Api::Building.find_by(id: params[:id])
  keys.map do |key, api_key|
    [
      key,
      building.attributes[key.to_s] || api_building.attributes[api_key.to_s]
    ]
  end.to_h
end
```

Comment: my question seem to lack more details , im sorry !

Comment: I also thought of that but I have table columns that have different names. I'm sorry I didn't include it in my question !

Comment: Updated an answer.

Comment: the reason why I don't accept params for get_building_info is because it is a ajax query so I only have id as a param for building.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. The method above does exactly what you want and it perfectly might be called without any parameter passed. As you might see, it has a default value for the argument.

Comment: I think this is very elegant, but what if there are only columns that can be taken from building_table and whether it exist or not it will be taken from building_table

Comment: Then pass `nil` or whatever inexisting in the respective position of the `api_keys`. This is not even close to elegant, this is the very common approach used everywhere in ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions may exist to achieve this, but however, here is a simpler solution:

```
def get_building_info
  building = Hash.new
  building[:name], building[:room] = desired_building.name, desired_building.room 
end

private

 def desired_building
    Building.find_by(id: params[:id]) || 
    Api::Building.find_by(id: params[:id])
 end
```

Comment: The problem is a certain attribute may be taken from api building but that doesn't mean other attributes will also be taken from api building.

Comment: You didn't get question of OP

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it in a correct way but `building` variable will be overwritten, you need to define a new variable like
`building2 = {}`

Comment: You didn't get question of OP

Comment: I'm sorry I just typed it in browser and it was a typo!

Answer (score 1):

```
before_action :find_records, only: :get_building_info

def get_building_info
  building_hash = {}
  building_hash[:name] = building_name
  building_hash[:room] = building_room
  # OR
  building_hash[:name], building_hash[:room] = building_name, building_room

end

private

def find_records
  @building = Building.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @api_building = Api::Building.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

def building_name
  @building.name || @api_building.name
end

def building_room
  @building.room || @api_building.room
end
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. My building model is composed of like 12 columns more , Do you think it is a good practice to have 12 of those on private ?

Comment: No its not ,. i thought you have only 2 parameters

Comment: Why not? You might easily generate all of them, so it’d take 5 lines for all the 12 methods.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin but 12 private methods, i think your solution is far better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
attrs = [ %i[name name], %i[room room], %i[rent monthly_fee] ]
attrs.each_with_object({}) do |(name, alias_name), h|
  h[name] = building[name] || api_building[alias_name]
end
```